# Angular 6 cookie expire or change event in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, cookies

Are there any events to invoke when cookie expires or while changing the cookie value in **angular 4** and latest.
I don't want to use a timer or interval?
To set and manage cookie I am using @angular2-cookie.

Comment: there is a simple event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/onChanged . Your question is really confusing because you use angularjs and speak about angular 6 and angular 4. and Your are using @angular2-cookie and you tag the question with javascript and jquery instead of Typescript. In any case if you are using angularjs or angular you could add an observable to this event and you will know how to do it. I tried to clarify your question, if my guess is correct I will provide you with an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this using **ng-idle** https://hackedbychinese.github.io/ng2-idle/
where I can manage cookies expiry and update on interrupts or in timeouts